# Do we need modify the configurations on the workers of spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

I did modify the configurations on the driver of spark cluster, such as the both  files of spark-defaults.conf and spark-env.sh. Do we need do the same things on the workers. It seems to not do those, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spark Properties** (`spark-defaults.conf`):

No. Properties are applications specific not a cluster wide so has to be set only in your Spark directory.

**Environment variables**:

Yes if you need custom settings. Environment variables are machine specific and don't depend on application.